# Specify postgresql database name in cloud foundry manifest.yml

Tags: postgresql, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

**Is there a way to specify a postgresql database name to connect to in the cloud foundry manifest.yml file?** I've been raking through the documentation and haven't yet found this specific information.

I'm imagining something like this:

```yaml
applications:
- name: my-app
  routes:
    - route: my-app.mybluemix.net
  services:
  - postgres
    dbname: database2
```

With that approach, a postgresql connection can be made by just the connection string provided by `VCAP_SERVICES` parsing modules ([cfenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cfenv) in the case of node).

If this is not possible, I will just set a `dbname` environment variable and build my own connection string.

Comment: Do you mean for a postgresql service instance also hosted on the cloud foundry, or one of your own?

Comment: nitind It is hosted in the same cloud foundry space.

Comment: That's usually handled by **binding** the service instance to the app.

Comment: Right, which can be done through the manifest. I've bound a postgres service before, but I want to know if it's possible to specify the postgres database name in the manifest service yaml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing like that in a Cloud Foundry application manifest.yml.

The manifest.yml only takes a list of service instance names and the services with those names will be bound to your app. It does not allow you set other metadata.

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest-attributes.html#services-block

I don't know if these will help, but when you `cf bind-service` directly there are two additional provisions you can make use of (these are not supported by manifest.yml as of me writing this):

- [Arbitrary bind parameters](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/application-binding.html#arbitrary-params-binding). These probably won't help unless your service broker supports them, but it's a way to pass additional info to the service broker. If your broker supported it, you could in theory say give me a database named XYZ by passing it some config this way.
- [Named service bindings](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/application-binding.html#service-binding-names). This provides what amounts to a second name. The intent is that you can create the service with a name of X, but your application can look for a service binding with name Y. You can use this to swap in differently named services, but still expose the same binding name to the application so it will always find the service.

If you are trying to pass in some other service instance related metadata to your application, you'd need to do it some other way. Like if you want to tell it the database name or the connection pool size, etc.. Using environment variables like you mentioned is one option. You could use a config file or cli arguments passed to your application. What you pick is probably a matter of preference/support in the library/framework you're using.

For what it's worth, most service brokers I've seen pass in and tell you a specific database name to use. If the broker said connect to db XYZ and you made your connection to myCoolDb, the connection would fail. Just wanted to mention this. Your mileage may vary.